# Callback when Nokia place data processed by template

Tags: javascript, here-api

Is there a callback function or any way to know when the place data has been processed with the template and injected into the page?

I want to update something else once the place data gets displayed.

I'm displaying my place information using:

```
var myPlace = new nokia.places.widgets.Place({
    placeId: "1234abcd",
    targetNode: "myPlaceContainer",
    template: "myPlaceContainer"
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `onData` and `onNoData` are user-defined functions applied to Place that can be used for this.

See: http://developer.here.net/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.places.widgets.Place.html#topic-apiref__Place-0

Still getting my head around using the documentation site.